# shellcode - simplifed code does not work

Tags: assembly, system-calls, shellcode

I dont know why but when I use the hex of below code as shell code it works:

```
Section .text
global _start
_start:
mov ebx,0
mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

but when I use the hex of the below code instead, it does not work and segmentation fault occurres:

```
Section .text
global _start
_start:
xor ebx,ebx
mov al,1
int 0x80
```

I know that is because of using 'al'. I don`t know why does using of 'eax' works correctly but using 'al' get error?

Thanks a lot.

Ya Ali.

Answer (score 1):

Because int 0x80 expects 32-bit param. When you pass low 8 bits only (AL), high parts of eax may contain anything (undefined value), so instead of passing 1 you end up passing 0x??????01

Comment: Thanks. I reading 2 books that use 'al' without any error. How can use 'al' correctly?

Comment: xor eax, eax\mov al, 1, but why? What's wrong with eax?

Comment: In shellcode '\x00' must not be appeared. When we use 'eax' \x00 is appeared. with using of 'al', there is no \x00 anymore

Comment: Try zeroing $eax first using the same xor trick you use on $ebx.  It's a month later than your question was asked, wheee!